# Get Primary key names from a table variable TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I get the primary key names from a declared table variable.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (id int PRIMARY KEY)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (id1 int, id2 int, id3 int PRIMARY KEY(id1, id2, id3))
```

The first example, I should expect `id` as the return value.

In the second example, I should expect `id1` `id2` `id3` as the return values.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears that you may be able to use standard management views. Have a look at this article.
https://www.sqlshack.com/the-table-variable-in-sql-server/

Comment: Smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) leading to an attempt to use dynamic sql with a local (table in this case) variable.

Comment: If you find yourself in need of this you are almost certainly not using a temp table when you should (assuming you need it at all, of course). In particular, you will get yourself into many more issues with scoping in attempts to use table variables dynamically than you would with a temp table.

Comment: Thanks everyone, suspected as much that this wasn't possible but wanted to check anyhow. The examples were existing dynamic scripts and wanted to see if I could reuse it.  I approached my problem from another angle.

Comment: It actually is possible to get the column details, it's just not useful because you can't use dynamic SQL